# Automated source dependancies

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, wstool, rosinstall, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to use

> wstool merge http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/joystick-drivers

in an overlay in such a way that it will only pull packages which are not already installed in a sub-layer?

For example: I have the mobile variant of ROS installed in /opt/ros/groovy and I set up an overlay at ~/groovy_workspace. I then want to download the joystick-drivers package and any dependencies which have not already been installed into my overlay.

My motivation is to avoid running cmake on the packages which I already have built.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55406/automated-source-dependancies/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2013-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

wstool merge --help gives you the options it has. --merge-keep does not quite do what you want, it does not detect that a package already exists in /opt/ros/groovy.

You could wget the url into a local file, then prune entries yourself, either manually or via a script. In python you could do that by yaml-parsing the rosinstall file you got via wget, giving you a list of dicts, then getting all packages you have installed, and removing those entries from the list, and then writing the remaining items into a file.

If enough people wanted this (indicated by +1 comments on my answer, or on a ticket on vcstools/rosinstall at github), we could maybe include such features, though probably into roslocate instead.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-17**:
+1 seems good to me. The question comes up frequently in one form or another.

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-02-17**:
+1 indeed, I have been doing it by hand as you suggested. This would be a great feature to have. :)